# how to add url behind this image

Tags: php, mysql, image, hyperlink

Hi this is custom PHP Admin Panel. I want to add URL Link in Admin Panel and attach each link for each image. Below is the code to add image

```
                                    while($client_images = mysql_fetch_array($client_images_query)){
                                    ?>
                                    <td class="response" style="width: 25%;">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 40%;" src="uploads/<?php echo $client_images['image']; ?>" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can surround the tag with

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 40%;" src="uploads/<?php echo $client_images['image']; ?>" alt="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="response" style="width: 25%;">
<a href="Your url">
<img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 40%;" src="uploads/
<?php echo $client_images['image']; ?>" alt="" />
</a>
```

Try this